# Why I failed to clone a git repository?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'm using Git Bash 2.9.0-64-bit in win7 64bit.

I created a git repository 'learnshell' in my own computer at home,and I pushed it to GitHub.
Then,I wanted to clone learnshell to my computer in my company.

But I failed, the directory is ~/home,it's not a git repository,here is my command
`git clone https:github.com/myname/learnshell.git`

And here is the corresponding result:

> Cloning into 'learnshell' ...
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname https:Name or service not known
>   Fatal: Coule not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I'm not using ssh because my company's network doesn't support it.

To solve this problem,I changed my directory and created an git repository named 'learnshell'.After that,I first ran command
 `git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/learnshell.git`,
then I ran
`git clone https://github.com/myname/learnshell`.
This time,the clone operation succeeded.
What's interesting is that after I changed my directory back to ~/home and ran the clone command,it succeeded too.

I don't know what's really happening beneath this phenomenon.So,Which git command makes the clone from a failure to a success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare for facepalm.

```
git clone https://github.com/myname/learnshell.git
```

You forgot the slashes.

Comment: That's the problem,I tried this command,and the results are exactly the same.`git clone https:/github.com/myname/learnshell.git` will cause the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Could not resolve hostname" indicates a problem using DNS. There was a problem converting the domain "github.com" into an IP address. Obviously, this is a networking (configuration) issue.

Because the commands you posted do not affect networking, it seems to me that the issue resolved itself by the time you entered the additional commands. It would have been a useful test at the time to attempt to connect to github.com via a web browser.